# Recursive/Reflective XSLT in .Net

Tags: .net, xslt, reflection, recursion

What I'd like to do is, from inside a (.Net) XSLT transformation, I will invoke a template that will return some XML, but the returned XML may itself include XSLT instructions to be processed. This process should operate recursively until there is no XSLT left, and then the output will be put into the result tree.

It may be that each "template" actually has to be a separate file, but I'd like to have the context (parameters, variables, and context nodes etc) maintained throughout the whole process, so just having recursive invocations of the Transform() method seems like it will not suffice.

A somewhat related question: say I call an extension function from inside a template. Is there a way to invoke a template from inside the extension function? It seems that the documentation on extension objects is extremely light - it tells you how to call it but doesn't document any parts of the xslt infrastructure I can interact with.

Apologies for not providing a decent concrete example but I'm in a research phase at the moment so it's all a bit abstract.

Andy

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Is this due to having multiple XML files to transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result of a transformation has nodes in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` namespace then you are dynamically generating XSLT, and to execute the generated XSLT you need to start/invoke a new transformation, it cannot be done from XSLT (at least not without an extension function).

> It may be that each "template"
>   actually has to be a separate file,
>   but I'd like to have the context
>   (parameters, variables, and context
>   nodes etc) maintained throughout the
>   whole process, so just having
>   recursive invocations of the
>   Transform() method seems like it will
>   not suffice.

You are talking about templates a lot, but XSLT operates with modules, templates is just one of the types of declarations a module can have. Why do you want parameters, variables, and context nodes to be mantained? After a transformation is done this information is no longer needed.

> A somewhat related question: say I
>   call an extension function from inside
>   a template. Is there a way to invoke a
>   template from inside the extension
>   function?

No, you cannot invoke a template from an extension function.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. The application I am researching is an XML based document assembly engine, and I was hoping to be able to use XSLT to embed logic inside the document fragments themselves. For instance, a document fragment could invoke a template or extension function to include another document fragment but that returned document fragment could itself also include logic and instructions to include other document fragments. I think it's clear that XSLT is not dynamic enough to handle this case so I am now looking at Powershell or .Net DLR instead.